# Can I retrieve the User Control from a TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls, treeview

I have a TreeView bound to data (MVVM model) where I am using a user control for the data display.

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate
          DataType="{x:Type vm:SiteViewModel}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <uc:MyUserControl x:Name="control1" Text="{Binding SiteName}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

When the item is selected, I need access to the user control itself.

I found an example of doing something similar to what I want but it used the TreeViewItem.Header.  In my code, because of the binding, the TreeViewItem.Header is the SiteViewModel object.

Is there an easy way of retrieving the actual user control (of type MyUserControl) from the TreeViewItem itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need access to the control? Why can't you instead access the control's view model and make modifications to that?

Comment: I need access to the control to set a property on it.  The user control will toggle between showing a TextBlock and a TextBox so that I can have 'in-place' editing in the TreeView.  That's the plan anyway, but I'm beginning to think it might be a bit advanced for me!  Maybe there's a better way of achieving this.

Comment: Yes, have a look into MVVM. This would allow you to manipulate the model rather than the view itself. The view would respond to changes in the model through data binding / triggers.

Comment: But, failing that, you can always use `LogicalTreeHelper` / `VisualTreeHelper` to dig through the tree to find your `UserControl` instance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you should specify `Command`, which will retrive or change some parameter. in your xaml, it will `Binding` on the property you want to change, may be with converter or without it. Such way is MVVM like. If you want to change Visibility between two controls, as in your case is TextBox and TextBlock, you should to create a `Visibility` variable in your View-Model which will represent its visibility, and bind it value to TextBox or to TextBlok. your xaml will contain following lines:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ReverseVisibilityConverter  />
</Window.Resources>
 ....
<TextBox Name="MyTB" Visibility="{Binding tbVisibility}" />
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyTB, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResources ReverseVisibilityConverter }}" />




public sealed class ReverseVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            var flag = (Visibility)value;
            if (flag == Visibility.Visible)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        catch
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((Visibility)value) == Visibility.Visible)
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            else
                return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        catch
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

where `local` is the namespace where your `Converter` defined and. You have denote, that `tbVisibility` - is the variable, which exist in `Ancestor DataContext`. Give me more info to help you, if it is not clear.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I have it working now by retrieving the user control using the VisualTreeHelper (thank to Kent) but I may revisit this to get a neater solution at some point.

Comment: I have now tried this approach as well, seeing as with the previous 'user control' implementation, when I added a new item to the TreeView I couldn't access either the new TreeViewItem nor the user control itself to set it into 'edit' mode. With this version, it works a bit better in that respect but I'd like to select all of the text and set the focus to the TextBox once a new item is added. My research into this so far has only served to show me that it might be quite tricky. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: the easeist method, but not `MVVM` like, is to handle event `SelectedItemChanged`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms595700.aspx) says, that `OnItemsChanged` is `protected`. If you want to access it, you need to derive your `OwnTreeView` from wpf `TreeView`. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) is a good article about behaviors & TreeView.

Comment: I will look into it.  Thanks once again.